# Should I have to upload SASS source files to Prestashop server?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass, prestashop-1.6

Prestashop theme folder contains a SASS folder. Where I am having .scss files for my newly developing theme. Am clear in compiling sass to css files locally, but prestashop is not having any inbuilt sass compiler, so does it makes any sense in uploading the sass folder to the server???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it does only make sense if you're using css-maps so you can actually use the scss instead of the compiled css to see the right lines in the inspect-element-console.

otherwise you don't need it.

//Edit might sounded confusing, what i mean is: You can actually see your scss-lines if you're using css-maps (the map needs the source to your scss-file) where all scss-commands you did are linked to the compiled css. if you inspect an element while having this css-map and the scss on the server and all file-directories correct then you'll see the scss-commands instead of the compiled css-commands. it makes developing much easier.